# Site redirecionado para página Nginx

Tags: nginx

Tentei acessar um site, pertencente à uma empresa, e ao invés de ser direcionado para a página do próprio site, fui redirecionado para uma página falando o seguinte:

> Welcome to nginx!
>
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.
>
> For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
>   Commercial support is available at nginx.com.
>
> Thank you for using nginx.

Meu sistema operacional é Windows 10 e uma outra pessoa já entrou nesse site pelo seu próprio computador e disse que conseguiu, logo o problema deve estar no meu computador.

Como proceder?

Agradeço desde já.

Comment: O endereço a que acedeste é exatamente o mesmo?

Comment: Sim, é o site tagon8.com, é exatamente o mesmo que a outra pessoa conseguiu acessar de forma normal.

Comment: Com ou sem `https`, com ou sem `www.`?

Comment: Sem ambos, mas testei agora com www e funcionou. Não sabia que fazia diferença. Muito obrigado

Comment: Se o servidor estiver mal configurado faz diferença. Devia estar a redirecionar `dominio` para `www.dominio` mas pelos vistos não está.

Answer (score 2):

Isto está ocorrendo por que no servidor nginx está tratando como server name apenas o endereço www.tagon8.com.

Para corrigir o erro basta colocar no server name o seguinte.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  www.tagon8.com tagon8.com;
    ...
}
```

Desta forma o nginx irá redirecionar ambos para o mesmo conteúdo.

Quanto a sua pergunta, isto não é problema do seu computador, navegador ou qualquer outro meio que esteja usando para acessar. Isto é má configuração no servidor.